# How to handle a job offer knowing that a couple of months later I might get a better one?

Tags: job-change

I have a bit of a tricky situation for me:

Right now I work in place A, and it is quite unsatisfying job.

I am also participating part time in a startup B with my friends, we have a few customers, but right now they are few and it is not at all enough to support the team.

I have a standing job offer from company C, and it is very good.

The dilemma for me is that I really like what I believe could become of the startup B, and it is plausible that over the next two months we'll get enough customers to have enough money to support us. (And then we'll be able to skip seed investments and get a better deal overall)

And corporate place C while being great otherwise will not have similar flexibility as a B, where I will have a lot of creative control over the project.

But it might just happen that C is not going to work out and I wouldn't shift to B fulltime any time soon, so it is really uncomfortable to decline the offer just so that I stayed for longer at place A.

I can see several possibilities, but maybe not all of them.
And I have a hard time comparing them:

1) Ask company C for 1 or 2 month to decide ( is it at all possible ? )
2) Accept offer from C, but if startup gains momentum -- leave ( doesn't seem nice, especially since first two months are mostly training )
3) Decline offer with positive feedback, and tell company C that I would really like to try again in half a year (possibility of being on unsatisfying job A for another 6 months or more)

Also don't really know what and when to tell my current management, since I haven't decided my course of action yet..

I would really appreciate any suggestions!

Comment: In general, you cant have the cake and eat it. There isnt a perfect solution to  always get the best possible outcome and NOT alienate any of the involved companies/people.  Be prepared to either make a decision and ride it out or compromise for less than "ideal" or be ready to burn bridges following a greedy algorithm approach. 
Personally, if I thought job B would satisfy me the most overall, I would go with it, do my best to have a killer product and pitch sales / marketing or what else is needed to make it a success.

Comment: The grass is always greener on the other side of the fence. Usually it is not. Just learn to be contentEd in life.

Comment: Heh - I just typed a nice answer but the question got closed.

Comment: 1 - go to C now.  2 - it's utterly OK to join C and leave in a few days or weeks.  3 - Don't be a "grass is greener" thinker.  4 - startups are a fantasy; totally forget about the issue.

Answer (score 5):

Make the decision based on what you have in front of you **now** not what **might** happen. If the startup gains momentum and you can't/don't want to sustain being involved in both then you can always leave A or C for it then but until that happens it's just so much "maybe".

Comment: I agree. You have no idea what might happen to the startup. Find the best solution for now, and if/when the time comes to switch to the startup, handle it as best as you can with company C. But this will be a completely different problem, different time, you cannot anticipate it properly now.